# Does the compiler optimize references to constant variables?

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization, memory-management

When it comes to the C and C++ languages, does the compiler optimize references to constant variables so that the program automatically knows what values are being referred to, instead of having to peek at the memory locations of the constant variables? When it comes to arrays, does it depend on whether the index value to point at in the array is a constant at compile time?

For instance, take a look at this code:

```
int main(void) {
    1:  char tesst[3] = {'1', '3', '7'};
    2:  char erm = tesst[1];
}
```

Does the compiler "change" line 2 to "char erm = '3'" at compile time?

Comment: It may or may not - depending on the compiler, its version, optimization levels, complexity of the code involved etc. Check the assembly your compiler generates for your target platform.

Comment: gcc6.2 does optimize as desired for -O1 or higher: https://godbolt.org/g/yFLoYo

Comment: You can somewhat easily answer these questions yourself by getting a disassembler and taking a look at the disassembled, optimized code. For example Codeblocks IDE - > Debugger windows -> Disassembly. You don't have to be an expert on x86 assembler to get the rough idea based on that.

Comment: afaik, in general `const` only means that the objects observable state cannot change. However, a `const` object may have `mutable` private fields, in which case it is not possible to use a copy instead of dereferencing the reference to the object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It mostly depends on the level of optimization and which compiler you are using.

With maximum optimizations, the compiler will indeed probably just replace your whole code with `char erm = '3';`. GCC -O3 does this anyway.

But then of course it depends on what you do with that variable. The compiler might not even allocate the variable, but just use the raw number in the operation where the variable occurs.

Answer (score 12):

I personally would expect the posted code to turn into "nothing", since neither variable is actually used, and thus can be removed.

But yes, modern compilers (gcc, clang, msvc, etc) should be able to replace that reference to the alternative with it's constant value [as long as the compiler can be reasonably sure that the content of `tesst` isn't being changed - if you pass `tesst` into a function, even if its as a `const` reference, and the compiler doesn't actually know the function is NOT changing that, it will assume that it does and load the value].

Compiling this using `clang -O1 opts.c -S`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char tesst[3] = {'1', '3', '7'};
    char erm = tesst[1];

    printf("%d\n", erm);
}
```

produces:

```
...

main:
    pushq   %rax
.Ltmp0:
    movl    $.L.str, %edi
    movl    $51, %esi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    callq   printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rcx
    retq

 ...
```

So, the same as `printf("%d\n", '3');`.

[I'm using C rather than C++ because it would be about 50 lines of assembler if I used `cout`, as everything gets inlined]

I expect gcc and msvc to make a similar optimisation (tested `gcc -O1 -S` and it gives exactly the same code, aside from some symbol names are subtly different)

And to illustrate that "it may not do it if you call a function":

```c
#include <stdio.h>

extern void blah(const char* x);

int main()
{
    char tesst[3] = {'1', '3', '7'};
    blah(tesst);
    char erm = tesst[1];

    printf("%d\n", erm);
}
```

```
main:                                   # @main
    pushq   %rax
    movb    $55, 6(%rsp)
    movw    $13105, 4(%rsp)         # imm = 0x3331
    leaq    4(%rsp), %rdi
    callq   blah
    movsbl  5(%rsp), %esi
    movl    $.L.str, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    callq   printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rcx
    retq
```

Now, it fetches the value from inside `tesst`.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the compiler version, optimization options used and many other things. If you want to make sure that the const variables are optimized and if they are compile time constants you can use something like **constexpr** in c++. It is guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time unlike normal const variables.

Edit: constexpr may be evaluated at compile time or runtime. To guarantee compile-time evaluation, we must either use it where a constant expression is required (e.g., as an array bound or as a case label) or use it to initialize a constexpr. so in this case

```
constexpr char tesst[3] = {'1','3','7'};
constexpr char erm = tesst[1];
```

would lead to compile time evaluation. Nice read at https://isocpp.org/blog/2013/01/when-does-a-constexpr-function-get-evaluated-at-compile-time-stackoverflow

Comment: If I had an integer variable i whose value is decided at execution time by user input and then called tesst[i]. Can the program be optimized for that too?

Comment: A `constexpr` expression is not guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time.  If the program is well-formed then it is always *possible* to evaluate a `constexpr` at compile time, but the compiler is not inherently obligated to perform that evaluation.  (The context in which such an expression is used could create such an obligation, however.)

Comment: @MånsNilsson Obviously, the compiler can't predict what the user will type. But it can predict that you only use 1 out of 3 bytes of the array and get rid of the not used ones.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Doesn't a `constexpr` variable have to be evaluated at compile time?

Comment: @NathanOliver, I'm open to being wrong on this, but I'm not finding anything in the standard that requires it in general.  `constexpr` expressions are subject to constraints that make it possible to evaluate them at compile time, but as far as I can tell, the standard does not insist that compile-time evaluation actually take place.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you seem to be right on this. I edited my answer to include your concerns.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I took another look and that does indeed look like the case.  Thanks.