# Two limited scope variables vs one global

Tags: c++, data-structures

Using C++, say I need the value of pi (3.14) for two functions. In regards to the performance of my program, which is better, declaring pi as a global variable and use it in both my functions or declaring it twice inside the functions as a limited scope variable that will die when each function goes out of memory? Obviously the difference is marginal for just this example, but if you multiply this case by x100 for a bigger program, maybe it will actually matter, that’s why I am asking.

Comment: Do you expect Pi to change? If not, define it as compile-time constant and the place does not matter. Even better, use C++20 `std::numbers::pi` or `std::numbers::pi_v`.

Comment: For constants make a header file with a namespace and add typed constants `inline constrexpr double pi=3.1415926532387979;` etc.. (do not use #define). Otherwise use local variables as much as you can. (No memory loads/cache misses etc.). In any case avoid global variables they will NOT improve performance but they will be bad for maintainability/(unit) testability

Comment: "maybe it will actually matter" you will know this when you have the bigger program and profile and measure it. Until then write code to be readable and maintainable, otherwise the project might not reach a stage where this detail matters

Comment: Not really the same question, but if you understand the answer to the following, then the answer to your question might follow: [Does the compiler optimize references to constant variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41224516) (Also, see keyword [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr))

Comment: You're using wrong tools for the job.  `pi` is a mathematical constant.   If you must define it (e.g. not using a C++ standard recent enough to provide it in a standard header) define it as a compile-time constant, not as a variable.     Then the question of variable scope (or variable lifetime) is irrelevant.   Only use variables for things that (ummm) can vary as your program executes.

Comment: Oh, and please don't just define it as `3.14`.   Define it to precision sufficient for how your code uses it  (e.g. if using it in floating point calculations, define it as a floating point value that is as accurate as possible with your floating point type)

Comment: Are you looking for the general rule of thumb advice based on other people's experience? Then you have it, "define it as compile-time constant". That advice is the same whether it's PI or not. Or are you asking specifically about when/whether you should use global variables (not compile-time constants). Then that advice has been given too, "avoid global variables". Or instead of the general advice, are you looking for some detailed analysis of the performance of global variables vs local variables? If so, you're trying to prematurely micro-optimize at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is *neither*.  Pi is a constant not a variable, and is defined in [`<numbers>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants) in C++20, or commonly by `M_PI` in `<math.h>` / `<cmath>` (requires `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` in [VC++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/math-constants?view=msvc-170), but not gnu or clang)

Certainly you should never have multiple independent instances of the same constant value; but it is less a performance issue and more a maintenance and consistency issue.  You would have multiple places in which to get it correct, and in the case if floating point values, may cause errors and discrepancies simply by using a differing number of significant digits for different definitions for irrational numbers such as pi.

For the more general question of how *any* constant might be defined, then I would suggest that `<numbers>` acts as an exemplar as to how it should be done.  The `std::numbers` constants are declared as `constexpr` in a *namespace*.

But it remains the case that neither approach will impact performance, but clearly multiple instances of the *same* `constexpr` remains ill-advised for the reasons already described not related to performance.

In some cases where the constant is part of a number of closely related classes and is itself very specialised (i.e. not general such as pi), you could make the constant a `static constexpr` member of a base class from which all other classes that use the constant are derived.

Either way the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle should be adhered to, which precludes multiple declarations of *any* constant.